# Remove duplicate lists from a list of lists, lists are unordered hashable objects

Tags: python, list, unordered

I have a list of lists, and I want to remove duplicates. The lists are unordered objects, and the system considers them to be different. 
For e.g.

```
a = [[1,2], [1,3], [3,4], [2,1] ,[4,3]]
```

I want the final result to be

```
b =  [[1,2], [1,3], [3,4]]
```

wherein the first occurrence is retained.

Comment: What language? What have you tried up to now?

Answer (score 0):

I use python to solve this problem.

```
a = [[1,2], [1,3], [3,4], [2,1] ,[4,3]]

for i in a:
    i.sort() # sort the inner list for [2,1] to [1,2]

b = set(map(tuple,a)) # convert the list to tuple for hashable
b = map(list,b) # covert again back to list

print b
```

Comment: If you have a list of `[[2, 1], [2,1]]` you're going to end up with an end result of `[[1, 2]]` which isn't going to be anything that was actually in the input list though...

Comment: yes then have to handle it logically like if len(a) > 1 then b execute and print. Thanks

Comment: instead of sorting the inner lists why not just `set(map(set, a))` (they are _unordered_, after all).

Comment: do you run set(map(set, a))? set is unhashable type here.